# Display portrait images in pairs using Cycle2

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, jquery-cycle2

I'm trying to create a picture portfolio of horizontal and vertical images in Wordpress using Cycle2, where all vertical (portrait) images are displayed in pairs. The following code works but it displays every image twice, once as current and once as next. How do I skip an image if it has been displayed before? Thanks!

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    );

    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    $length = count($attachments);
    for($i = 0; $i < $length ; ++$i) {
       $attachment = current($attachments);
       $next_attachment = next($attachments);                   
       $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'large' ); 
       $next_image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $next_attachment->ID, 'large' ); 
       $w = $image_attributes[1];
       $h = $image_attributes[2]; 
       $nw = $next_image_attributes[1];
       $nh = $next_image_attributes[2]; 
           if($h > $w & $nh > $nw) {
               echo '<li>';
               echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
               echo wp_get_attachment_image( $next_attachment->ID, 'large' );
               echo '</li>';
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve's logic is right but in order for `current` and `next` to work, a `for` loop needs to be used. All I needed to do is count all portrait instances and output only the odd ones. The following works:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'orderby' => menu_order,
'order' => 'ASC'
);

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
$length = count($attachments);
$counter = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < $length ; ++$i) {
    $attachment = current($attachments);
    $next_attachment = next($attachments);                   
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
    $next_image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $next_attachment->ID, 'large' ); 
    $w = $image_attributes[1];
    $h = $image_attributes[2];
    $nw = $next_image_attributes[1];
    $nh = $next_image_attributes[2];
    if($h > $w) {
        $counter++;
        if(($nh > $nw) and ($counter % 2 == 1)) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $next_attachment->ID, 'large' );
            echo '</li>';
        } elseif(($nh < $nw) and ($counter % 2 == 1)) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
            echo '</li>';
        } elseif((!$next_attachment) and ($counter % 2 == 1)) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
            echo '</li>';
        }
    } elseif($h < $w) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
        echo '</li>';
        $counter = 0;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to run a regular loop, and only output `li` elements every other iteration:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
);

$attachments = get_posts( $args );
echo '<li>';
$counter=0;
foreach($attachments as $attachment){


    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
    $w = $image_attributes[1];
    $h = $image_attributes[2];
    if($h > $w) {
        $counter++;
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'portfolio' );
        if($counter %2 == 0){
            echo '</li><li>';
        }
    }

}
echo '</li>';
```

Comment: Thanks but the portfolio will not only consist of portrait images, so i need to include some sort of statement where only portrait images get skipped.

Comment: @MrArkadin Ah yes, missed that - i have made an edit, so the counter is only increased for portfolio images.

Comment: I tried to make this work but it seems that "next" and "current" don't work as expected inside the foreach loop, therefore I can't count the dimensions of the next attachement